# delete x vs ::operator delete(x)

Tags: c++

What is the difference between `delete x;` and `::operator delete(x);`? I understand they are different, but I can't figure out quite what the difference is. My specific use case is that I have an object that must be allocated with `::operator new(size_t)` and later initialized with the placement new operator. However, I would really like to be able to deallocate it with `delete x;` rather than `::operator delete(x);`, so I would like to know when these two methods (no pun intended) might do different things, so I can tell when (if ever) it is safe to use them interchangably.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of what you're talking about? It's not clear the reason you're calling new the way you are. It seems there's some context you're leaving out that an example might provide.

Comment: "*I have an object that must be allocated with `::operator new(size_t)`*" - why not with `new byte[]` or `new uint8_t[]` or `new char[]` instead?  You can use `placement new` with such memory. You would just have to use `delete[]` instead of `delete`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete x` is a [`delete expression`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete).

`::operator delete(x)` is a [`deallocation function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

The delete expression will call the destructor (if it exists) and then the deallocation function. Calling the deallocation function directly will bypass the destructor.

Comment: Then is `delete x;` always equivalent to `x.~T(); ::operator delete(x);`?

Comment: It would be `x->~T();`, and there might be custom `operator delete` for the class

Comment: It would be good to cover that if there is a custom deallocator for `T` then `::operator delete()` is different

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that `::operator delete()` will not call destructors where `delete` would.